# How to check if EDID can be tusted

Tags: bash, xorg, edid

`read-edid` gives me the message *"The EDID data should not be trusted as the VBE call failed"*. Thats okay, but I want to find out, that this data is not reliable, another way, because I can't use read-edid on our system. Personally I can find it out studying the Xorg.log, but imho this would be a pretty improper way.

Is there a nice way to check the reliability of the EDID data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `xrandr --verbose`. It shows the raw edid detail as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try [`monitor-edid`](http://wiki.mandriva.com/en/Tools/monitor-edid). Home page describes the various methods used to access the `EDID`. I found it more flexible and reliable than `read-edid`. It also has some nice output options.
via VBE:

```
monitor-get-edid-using-vbe | monitor-parse-edid

parsing EDID from /sys/class/drm/card0-LVDS-1/edid
EISA ID: CMO1574
EDID version: 1.3
EDID extension blocks: 0
Screen size: 34.4 cm x 19.3 cm (15.53 inches, aspect ratio 16/9 = 1.78)
Gamma: 2.2
Digital signal

    # Monitor preferred modeline (60.0 Hz vsync, 55.5 kHz hsync, ratio 16/9, 118 dpi)
    ModeLine "1600x900" 97.75 1600 1648 1680 1760 900 903 908 926 -hsync -vsync
```

via KMS (perl dumper format):

```
monitor-edid -v --perl
(
parsing EDID from /sys/class/drm/card0-LVDS-1/edid
+{
          'EISA_ID' => 'CMO1574',
          'checksum' => 25,
          'detailed_timings' => [
                                  {
                                    'ModeLine' => '"1600x900" 97.75 1600 1648 1680 1760 900 903 908 926 -hsync -vsync',
                                    'ModeLine_comment' => '# Monitor preferred modeline (60.0 Hz vsync, 55.5 kHz hsync, ratio 16/9, 118 dpi)',
                                    'digital_composite' => 3,
                                    'horizontal_active' => 1600,
                                    'horizontal_blanking' => 160,
                                    'horizontal_border' => 0,
                                    'horizontal_dpi' => '118.139534883721',
                                    'horizontal_image_size' => 344,
                                    'horizontal_sync_offset' => 48,
                                    'horizontal_sync_positive' => 0,
                                    'horizontal_sync_pulse_width' => 32,
                                    'interlaced' => 0,
                                    'pixel_clock' => '97.75',
                                    'preferred' => 1,
                                    'stereo' => 0,
                                    'vertical_active' => 900,
                                    'vertical_blanking' => 26,
                                    'vertical_border' => 0,
                                    'vertical_dpi' => '118.445595854922',
                                    'vertical_image_size' => 193,
                                    'vertical_sync_offset' => 3,
                                    'vertical_sync_positive' => 0,
                                    'vertical_sync_pulse_width' => 5
                                  }
                                ],
          'diagonal_size' => '15.5292379824145',
          'edid_revision' => 3,
          'edid_version' => 1,
          'established_timings' => [],
          'extension_flag' => 0,
          'feature_support' => {
                                 'DPMS_active_off' => 0,
                                 'DPMS_standby' => 0,
                                 'DPMS_suspend' => 0,
                                 'GTF_compliance' => 0,
                                 'has_preferred_timing' => 1,
                                 'rgb' => 0,
                                 'sRGB_compliance' => 0
                               },
          'file' => '/sys/class/drm/card0-LVDS-1/edid',
          'gamma' => 120,
          'manufacturer_name' => 'CMO',
          'max_size_horizontal' => '34.4',
          'max_size_precision' => 'mm',
          'max_size_vertical' => '19.3',
          'monitor_details' => '',
          'monitor_text' => [
                              'N156O6-L01',
                              'CMO',
                              'N156O6-L01'
                            ],
          'product_code' => 5492,
          'ratio' => '1.78238341968912',
          'ratio_name' => '16/9',
          'ratio_precision' => 'mm',
          'serial_number' => 0,
          'standard_timings' => [],
          'video_input_definition' => {
                                        'composite_sync' => 0,
                                        'digital' => 1,
                                        'separate_sync' => 0,
                                        'sync_on_green' => 0,
                                        'voltage_level' => 0
                                      },
          'week' => 41,
          'year' => 2008
        }
,
)
```

Comment: Great answer as well. But I need less dependencies for our minimal system. Thanks anyway!